# How can I properly utilize "time elapsed" when predicting the probability of a binary outcome?

Tags: regression, classification, survival, time-varying-covariate

I have historical data about people who went through a process, all of whom, after waiting a number of days, either succeeded or failed. I have the number of days it took them to reach the final outcome (`days_till_outcome`), and whether the outcome was success or failure (`succeeded` boolean). I also have some unchanging-over-time predictors for each person (things like `exam_score`).

I want to train a model on that historical data, in order to make predictions for people currently in the process, for whom I want to predict probability of ultimately passing, and predict the number of days until reaching the final outcome. Of course, I don't have `succeeded` boolean or `days_till_outcome` for them, as those are the essentially response variables I'm trying to predict, but importantly, I do have new different variable that isn't in the training data, namely `days_elapsed_so_far`. But I don't know how to utilize it properly.

Right now I have two separate gradient-boosting tree models: a basic regression model to predict the days-to-outcome, and a basic classifier to predict the probability of passing. Both models' predictions (i.e., probability of success, and days-till-outcome) are based on the unchanging-over-time predictors only. So my prediction won't take into account if they've been waiting for 2 days (everyone waits way more than 2 days, so it's not informative) or 100 days (maybe only people who end up failing wait that long, and that should influence my prediction.).

My first question is, how can I utilize `days_elapsed_so_far` when I'm making predictions, given that `days_elapsed_so_far` (a variable I have for people still in the process) doesn't mean `days_till_outcome` (which is a response variable in the training set), but rather it means 'days elapsed so far without the outcome occurring'? I don't think I can treat these two variables as if they mean the same thing, because when John Doe has been waiting 10 days for a decision, I don't want to ask my model "How likely is John Doe to pass given that they got their decision in 10 days?", but rather I want to ask "How likely is John Doe to pass given that they've been waiting for a decision for 10 days so far?".

My initial idea: for each person in the training set, turn the person into $n-1$ data points, where $n$ is their `days_till_outcome`. In that case, every column except `days_elapsed_so_far` will repeat across the $n-1$ data points, and the outcome columns will also repeat, but `days_elapsed_so_far` will vary, so that every value in $[0, n-1]$ appears in a unique row. The idea is that anyone who got their decision in $n$ days passed through a day where the days elapsed so far would have been 1 day, 2 days, ... , $n-1$ days. These data points are like snapshots of those days, paired with the known final outcome. As long as I make sure all $n$ of those point end up exclusively on one side of the train-test split, this seems legitimate. I could then use `days_elapsed_so_far` like a run-of-the-mill numeric feature, and the model could at least of a chance of learning that the people who wait the longest for a decision tend to succeed (or vice versa). Is this a recommendable approach? It seems like it could work but that it's tacky. Is there some other way to featurize my data so that every day that goes by I could re-run the model predictions and have a slightly different/updated prediction for everyone's pass probability? What is the standard approach for this kind of situation?

My second question is whether I could use a single, more comprehensive model that jointly predicts pass probability and days-till-outcome, and if so, what kind of model that would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion on how to proceed by employing your predicted probability (say 'p') of 'ultimately passing' together with the observed number of days until reaching the final outcome.

Importantly, is this data consistent with a Geometric Probability Law based on p?

If yes, the process is without memory, to quote [Wikipedia as a source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution):

> Like its continuous analogue (the exponential distribution), the geometric distribution is memoryless. That means that if you intend to repeat an experiment until the first success, then, given that the first success has not yet occurred, the conditional probability distribution of the number of additional trials does not depend on how many failures have been observed.

And as such, you should not attempt to use *days_elapsed_so_far* as a variable.

Otherwise, however, one may be able to employ a Weibull based failure/success law, as to [quote Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution):

> the Weibull distribution gives a distribution for which the failure rate is proportional to a power of time...

Note: you can still make a prediction as to the # of days required on average based on the Geometric distribution (namely, 1/p).

[EDIT] Per a comment, I cite the general reference to Reliability Theory (a course I actually have the pleasure of taking). Here is an introduction [courtesy of ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/reliability-theory), to quote:

> Reliability theory has grown in the last six decades into an independent discipline by drawing tools from several areas including mathematics, statistics probability theory, and actuarial science. During the course of solving its problems, reliability analysis have contributed several concepts and theorems to many other subjects. These topics have resulted in opening up new areas of investigation in several fields of scientific activity.

Comment: IMO, you may want to consider, or at least mention, the wide range of survival or time-to-events models that were developed in the past 30+ years to enhance this answer.